# Wordpress Get Images using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, function

I have an old function which uses the post excerpt to hold the image thumbnail. It was a bit hackey and worked for a long time.

Now I need to use the post excerpt for, you know, an excerpt. So I'm looking to update this function to grab the image src info straight from the post attachments instead.

The question:

How can I update the `$before_sql` SQL code below to grab the first attached image in the post attachment?

The code:

(I think I am only concerned about the sql portion as the rest should clean itself up?) There's more code section too, but instead of pasting ALL of it here, this snippet should be enough.

```
$before_sql = "SELECT ID, post_title, post_excerpt FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' and post_date < '$cur_post_date' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $thumbnum";
$before_results = $wpdb->get_results($before_sql);
if($before_results) {
    foreach ($before_results as $before_result) {
        $post_title = stripslashes($before_result->post_title);
        $permalink = get_permalink($before_result->ID);
        $post_excerpt = ($before_result->post_excerpt);
        $output="<div class=\"thumbnails\"><a href=\"" . $permalink . "\" title=\"Permanent Link: " . $post_title . "\">" . $post_excerpt . "</a><br />&lsaquo;</div>\n         " . $output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the first attachment with the posts in one query you can do in this way

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT guid FROM `wp_posts`  WHERE post_type ='attachment' AND post_parent=wp.`ID` ORDER BY post_date ASC LIMIT 1 ) AS attachment
 FROM `wp_posts` wp
```

**ORDER BY post_date ASC** will get the first image if you want the latest uploaded image you can simply use DESC **ORDER BY post_date DESC**

Here is your query

```
$before_sql = "SELECT ID, post_title, post_excerpt,
(SELECT guid FROM $wpdb->posts  WHERE post_type ='attachment' AND post_parent=wp.`ID`
ORDER BY post_date ASC LIMIT 1 ) AS attachment
FROM $wpdb->posts wp WHERE wp.post_status = 'publish' AND wp.post_type = 'post'
and wp.post_date < '$cur_post_date' ORDER BY wp.post_date DESC LIMIT $thumbnum";
```

It works fine for me

This is the query which will fetch those posts only which has the attachments on it

```
$before_sql = "SELECT ID, post_title, post_excerpt,
(SELECT guid FROM $wpdb->posts  WHERE post_type ='attachment' AND post_parent=wp.`ID`
ORDER BY post_date ASC LIMIT 1 ) AS attachment
FROM $wpdb->posts wp WHERE wp.post_status = 'publish' AND wp.post_type = 'post'
and wp.post_date < '$cur_post_date' HAVING attachment IS NOT NULL ORDER BY wp.post_date DESC LIMIT $thumbnum";
```

Comment: Can't seen to get it to work, and a `var_dump($before_sql)` shows `NULL`. I think the issue might be `post_parent=wp.'ID'`. How can I refine that to be the post ID? I have `global $id` defined. `post_parent=wp.'$id'`fails too.

Comment: why you var_dump(sql) ?? you need to do `$before_results = $wpdb->get_results($before_sql);`  and `post_parent=wp.`ID`` is the correlating alias to pass in subquery run my first query in phpmyadmin you can see it working

Comment: Yes, now I see it's working. Except Using ID`` or `'ID'` gave me a NULL on the attachment in the foreach.

Comment: yes null for attachment if the post don't has attachments if post has attachments then it will show the url of image or attachment try to upload the images on any post and then see

Comment: Yeah, this is on a photoblog site with 500 images. I can see post_title, and ID, but attachment is null. I can't even get this to work: `$beforeIMG = wp_get_attachment_url($before_result->ID);` however `echo $before_result->ID;` works fine. There are images uploaded that it should be showing.

Comment: I see your edited answer, thanks. As it is right now that appears to work a lot better.